# Specific localization server for a module

Tags: hooks, i18n-l10n

Hello fellow Drupal developers...

When installing a new language, the [Localization Update](https://drupal.org/project/l10n_update) module downloads the necessary (.po) files from Drupal's localization server.  However, is there a way to specify where a module should download this from?

This shouldn't be for ALL of the modules, but only a package of modules or just one single module.

Is there a hook, or some sort of info configuration we can place in the module's .info file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an alternative source for translations in .info file in different ways:

```
l10n server = http://example.com

l10n url = http://example.com/path/to/l10n_server.xml

l10n path = http://example.com/path/to/%core/%project/%project-%release.%language.po
```

If your localization server is based in [l10n_server](https://drupal.org/project/l10n_server) module, `l10n server` is enough.

If you're not using l10n_server but a custom solution, you may want to provide `l10n url` key with the url to a custom-build xml file to inform l10n_update about where to get translation updates from.

Lastly, if you're not using l10n_update and you're not planning to generate such an update xml file, you can pass the path to the .po file with `l10n path`, you can use some placeholders in this path, as shown above.

For more information, see l10n_update's README.txt and docstrings for l10n_update_build_projects().